# How to upload an image to webapp/resources/images directory using spring mvc?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have repository class where I want to store the image that is coming from MultipartFile to webapp/resources/images directory before adding the product details to the repository ?

```
@Override
public void addProduct(Product product) {
    Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource("file:webapp/resources/images");

     MultipartFile proudctImage = product.getProudctImage();

     try {
        proudctImage.transferTo(new File(resource.getFile()+proudctImage.getOriginalFilename()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    listOfProducts.add(product);
}
```

my repository class is ResourceLoaderAware. I am getting fileNotFoundException, "imagesDesert.jpg" is the image I am trying to upload

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: webapp\resources\imagesDesert.jpg (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Comment: Adding file to the classpath can make your container restart (I think about tomcat), that's not a good idea. What is the purpose of that (what problem are you trying to solve)

Comment: I have updated my code in the question, what I am trying is to upload an product image during adding a product and would like to show that image in the product details page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I could able to fix this problem, we need not specify the **file:** prefix, and moreover by default `resourceLoader.getResource()` will look for resources in the root directory of our web application, So no need of specifying the `webapp` folder name. So finally the following code works for me

```
@Override
public void addProduct(Product product) {

    MultipartFile proudctImage = product.getProudctImage();

    if (!proudctImage.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            proudctImage.transferTo(resourceLoader.getResource("resources/images/"+product.getProductId()+".png").getFile());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Product Image saving failed", e);
        }
    }

    listOfProducts.add(product);
}
```

Answer (score 10):

this controller (courtesy: https://askgif.com/) is working fine for me.

source: [https://askgif.com/blog/126/how-can-i-upload-image-using-spring-mvc-java/](https://askgif.com/blog/126/how-can-i-upload-image-using-spring-mvc-java/?source=stackoverflow)

try this

```
package net.viralpatel.spring3.controller;


import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import net.viralpatel.spring3.form.FileUploadForm;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;


@Controller
 public class FileUploadController {

//private String saveDirectory = "D:/Test/Upload/"; //Here I Added
private String saveDirectory = null; //Here I Added

@RequestMapping(value = "/show", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String displayForm() {
    return "file_upload_form";
}

@SuppressWarnings("null")
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String save(
        @ModelAttribute("uploadForm") FileUploadForm uploadForm,
                Model map,HttpServletRequest request) throws IllegalStateException, IOException{

    List<MultipartFile> files = uploadForm.getFiles();
    List<String> fileUrl = new ArrayList<String>();;
    String fileName2 = null;
    fileName2 = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");


    saveDirectory = fileName2+"images\\";

    List<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<String>();

    //System.out.println("user directory : "+System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    System.out.println("applied directory : " + saveDirectory);
    if(null != files && files.size() > 0) {
        for (MultipartFile multipartFile : files) {

            String fileName = multipartFile.getOriginalFilename();
            System.out.println("applied directory : " + saveDirectory+fileName);
            if(!"".equalsIgnoreCase(fileName)){
                   //Handle file content - multipartFile.getInputStream()
                   fileUrl.add(new String(saveDirectory + fileName));

                   multipartFile.transferTo(new File(saveDirectory + fileName));   //Here I Added
                   fileNames.add(fileName);
                   }
            //fileNames.add(fileName);
            //Handle file content - multipartFile.getInputStream()
            //multipartFile.transferTo(new File(saveDirectory + multipartFile.getOriginalFilename()));   //Here I Added
        }
    }

    map.addAttribute("files", fileNames);
    map.addAttribute("imageurl",fileUrl);
    return "file_upload_success";
}
  }
```

Comment: Hi Sumit, this is a good approach indeed, but I am in repository, I don't have access to `HttpServletRequest`, my repository already implements `ResourceLoaderAware`. So is there any way I can get `request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/")` through `resource `

Comment: finally I used your approach....instead of saving the image from repository I have saved in the controller itself

Comment: Hi Sumit, your answer is one kind of approach to the problem, but that is not the exact answer for the question. finally I found the answer my self, any how thanks a lot for your time and help

Comment: No problem, we are only assisting you here, it's not our job to complete your task. :)